# RT Sql Layer plugin giving an error

Tags: python, postgis, qgis

I am trying to use the aforementioned plugin with QGIS 1.7 and Postgres 9.0/PostGIS 1.5.

Added a PostGIS spatial layer w/out a problem and then clicked on the RT Sql layer button which displayed the main dialog. When I select Database-> , I got this error

BTW - the **...**'s is the QGIS plugin path. Left it out for clarity):

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\ManagerWindow.py", line 112, in dbConnectSlot
    self.dbConnect( self.sender() )
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\ManagerWindow.py", line 163, in dbConnect
    self.refreshTable()
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\ManagerWindow.py", line 272, in refreshTable
    model.loadFromDb(self.db)
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\DatabaseModel.py", line 250, in loadFromDb
    self.tree.constructTreeFromDb(self.db)
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\DatabaseModel.py", line 96, in constructTreeFromDb
    list_tables = db.list_geotables()
  File ".../python/plugins\rt_sql_layer\connectors\postgis.py", line 275, in list_geotables
    items[i] = geo_item
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Python version:
2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.7.0-Wroclaw Wroclaw, 63ecdd7
```

I never used python in the past but I had a look at the source code and it seems that the query the plugin is running to get the spatial tables into a tree view is not returning anything? Had a go to running the sql statements in PostGIS and they all seem to return data. Then again- not sure if I am looking at the right place!

Have you seen this before? Has it got anything to do with the s/w versions? Plugin was developed for an earlier version and **something** has changed in the latest?

Comment: I had the same error before, but as I closed the also-ruuning PostGIS Manager, the RT sql layer ran well！

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).